How to handle frequently changing group counts?
I am facing a problem, don't know the best practice.
The Problem: When new data is created, one of its field either be group X or group Z. Group counts must be balanced after some time. Like we can assign to Group Z if last one was Group X.
Z-X-Z-X.. should be fine.
We can count the Z and X and then assign the new one to a group, but in this way everytime I create new data, I have to count X and Z group on database.
We can use cache but it seems bad practice because counts are changing frequently.
What is the best option?

If you have an auto increment integer ID column, you can check ID%2 and if the result is 0 assign to Z and if the result is 1 assign to X, this way no need to count groups any more.

very good idea, thank you. But in this situation, I need to do save process twice, because id is unknown at that time, right?

Correct. You can't reference an auto-increment in a before trigger, nor can you use it in a generated column. The only way is to complete the INSERT, then once the id is known, UPDATE the row again.

@ozkanpakdil there is absolutely no guarantee that auto increment numbers are consecutive

@Shadow I just wanted to show a different way, many database issues can be solved from design, especially this kind of issues, if he designs differently he may get rid of those category tables too. And what is the best solution do you suggest ?

I'm not sure if I left this task to the database to do. A semaphore can do it in java. If the OP insists on database, then copy  a semaphore-like bahaviour in mysql using locks.
